# tkinter can not display the image

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to put an image(light.gif) in the button of tkinter.
However, the image is not shown and only a small transparent box appears at the specified position.

My Code is

```
from tkinter import* #To use Tkinter
from tkinter import ttk #To use Tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox #To use Tkinter
import tkinter.font # To use Font

win = Tk()
win.title("Main Control")
win.geometry('450x400+100+300')
win.resizable(0,0)

def a1():
     a1 = Toplevel()
     a1.title("a1")
     a1.geometry('450x350+560+100')
     a1.resizable(0,0)

     lignt_sensor_image=PhotoImage(file = 'light.gif')
     light_sensor_button=Button(a1,width=15,height=8)
     light_sensor_button.place=(x=275,y=200)
     a1.mainloop()

newa1 = Button(win, text='A1', font=font1, command=a1, height = 5, width = 10)
newa1.place(x=50, y=30)
win.mainloop()
```

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must keep a reference to the image; as it is created in a function, it was destroyed the moment the function exited.
There also were typos in your code that prevented it from running.

The following shows your image in the popup window.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import PhotoImage


def spawn_toplever_a1(): 
    global light_sensor_image                  # <- hold the image in the global variable, so it persists
    a1 = tk.Toplevel()                         # do not name your variables the same as your function
    a1.title("a1")
    a1.geometry('450x350+560+100')
    light_sensor_image = PhotoImage(file='light.gif')
    light_sensor_button = tk.Button(a1, image=light_sensor_image, text="my image", compound="center")

    light_sensor_button.place(x=275,y=100)   # <-- typo - removed '=' sign
                                             # <-- removed call to mainloop

light_sensor_image = None                    # declare variable to hold the image

win = tk.Tk()
win.title("Main Control")
win.geometry('450x400+100+300')
win.resizable(0,0)    

newa1 = tk.Button(win, text='A1', command=spawn_toplever_a1, height = 5, width = 10)
newa1.place(x=50, y=30)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Considering what you told me, it runs cleanly.
Thank you!